# C++ Have One Nested Class Inherit From Another Nested Class

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, nested-class

I'm writing a cross-platform class hierarchy, and want to keep the platform dependent implementations in their own class (as opposed to having one class with `#ifdefs`). This is what I have so far, but the compiler is complaining that `BaseDef` is private. Any help with how I could keep this basic structure while getting it to compile would be greatly appreciated :-)

**Edit:** It would seem from [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/85553-friend-cannot-inherit-private-subclass.html) that this isn't possible. Any other way I could keep this general structure and still compile?

Root.h

```
class Root {
    private:
        class BaseDef {
            virtual void foo() = 0;
            virtual void bar() = 0;
        };

        #ifdef _WIN32
        class WinImp;
        #else
        class NixImp;
        #endif

        BaseDef* imp;

        BaseDef* getImp();

    public:
        Root() : imp(getImp()) {}
        void foo();
        void bar();
};
```

Root.cpp

```
#include "Root.h"
void Root::foo() {
    imp->foo();
}

void Root::bar() {
    imp->bar();
}
```

WinImp.h

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Root.h"
class WinImp : public Root::BaseDef {
    public:
        void foo();
        void bar();
};
#endif
```

WinImp.cpp

```
#include "WinImp.h"
#ifdef _WIN32
    Root::WinImp::foo() {

    }

    Root::WinImp::bar() {

    }

    Root::BaseDef* Root::getImp() {
        return new Root::WinImp();
    }
#endif
```

Comment: Ack… using a singleton instance as a namespace with static members… better to use namespaces.

Comment: @Potatoswatter this has all of my code stripped out of it (obviously :-) ).... In practice it can't be a namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `BaseDef` is private. That means that other classes (aside from Root itself) cannot access the `BaseDef` name. One way is to make `BaseDef` public. Alternatively you can make the derived classes (`WinImp` and `NixImp`) friends of `Root` so that they can access the `BaseDef` name. In addition `Root` cannot access the members of `BaseDef` so they need to be public or make `Root` a friend of `BaseDef`.

```
class Root {
private:
  class BaseDef {
  public:
    // These need to be public so that Root can see them or Root needs to be a friend. 
    //Nothing else can see BaseDef though so this is safe.
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void bar() = 0;
  };

  class WinImp; // Forward declare the classes
  friend class WinImp; // And then make them friends
  class NixImp;
  friend class NixImp;

  BaseDef* imp;

  BaseDef* getImp();

public:
  Root() : imp(getImp()) {}
  void foo();
  void bar();
};

void Root::foo() {
  imp->foo();
}

void Root::bar() {
  imp->bar();
}

// Since this is a nested class i made it Root::WinImp
class Root::WinImp : public Root::BaseDef {
public:
  void foo();
  void bar();
};

void Root::WinImp::foo() {}

void Root::WinImp::bar() {}

Root::BaseDef* Root::getImp() {
  return new WinImp();
}
```

This method is not allowed according to the 2003 standard (11.4.p2) but in C++11 (same example) it is explicitly allowed (11.3.p2). However, clang (3.1 tested) accepts this even in 2003 mode. gcc (4.7.2 tested) accepts this (even in 2003 mode) so long as the derived classes are nested inside the same class but not if outside the class.

Comment: I initially thought this would work, but it still won't compile. See http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/85553-friend-cannot-inherit-private-subclass.html

Comment: @Eliezer It compiles fine here with all combinations of my suggested changes (using clang 3.1). It appears in that case i have found a compiler bug. Will update my answer if i figure out a better way.

Comment: @Eliezer I think i know what the problem is. The spec quoted is the 2003 edition. The compiler i am using is 2011. The quote on that site is correct as of the 2003 standard but the equivalent section of the 2011 spec 11.3.p2 seems to explicitly allow what i wrote. If you have a recent compiler you might want to try adding the appropriate option to support C++11 if available.

Comment: Sucks that there's no way to do it with 2003. I'll try switching compilers

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I tried GCC 4.7.2 with the -std=c++11 option and it doesn't work

Comment: I was using clang 3.1. Found a couple of problems that were hidden by your use of `_WIN32` and me not being on Windows. I left that stuff in the header but i didn't copy it for the implementation. The end result is that my changing from `class XXXImp` to `friend class XXXImp` made the Imp classes global classes and not nested. Since your `WinImp` is wrongly also global it was accepted. The end result though is that after fixing your mistakes and my faulty copying it turns out clang works correctly nested and global. gcc only accepts them nested. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining that `BaseDef` is `private`...

```
class Root {
    private:
        class BaseDef {
            virtual void foo() = 0;
            virtual void bar() = 0;
        };
```

So make it public...

```
class Root {
    public:
        class BaseDef {
            virtual void foo() = 0;
            virtual void bar() = 0;
        };
```

**Footnote:**

You're trying to avoid `#ifdef`, so get rid of this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
class WinImp;
#else
class NixImp;
#endif
```

Instead, just use a single class:

```
class Imp;
```

Comment: I don't want anyone to be able to access `BaseDef` though.

I wanted to keep `WinImp` and `NixImp` mostly for readability. I'll take the `#ifdef` in `Root` because there shouldn't be any maintenance in there

Comment: As an alternative to making `BaseDef` public you could make the implementation classes (`WinImp` and `NixImp`) friends of `Root`. That would allow them to access the private members of `Root` including `BaseDef`.

Comment: So nested classes aren'e friends by default?

Comment: @Eliezer Nope. They are just like any other class. That is also precisely why you are getting complaints about `BaseDef` being private.

Comment: @John5342 Thanks. I'll try that. You want to put that in an answer so I can give it you?

Comment: @Eliezer Done. Mostly so i can add an example which is not so easy in comments :-)